# Is it possible that any spatial variation in press disturbance without gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, stability

When gravity (and buoyancy), acting as the only body force of a liquid, is ignored. Is it possible that any spatial variations in pressure perturbation are the result of fluid motion or some other effects?

Comment: What is cause and what is the effect -- do pressure perturbations cause fluid motion? Or does fluid motion cause pressure disturbances?

Comment: @tpg2114, I mean that is it possible that any spatial variations in pressure perturbation are they the result of fluid motion?

Comment: I know your question but it's not the right question to ask. Think about what I asked in my comment - which is the cause and which is the effect - and you will be able to answer your own question. It may lead to different questions of course.